# How to mount a device read-only with Python3 and Udisks2?

Tags: python-3.x, glib, udisks

I need to (temporary) mount a device read-only with Python3 and the Udisks2 API. What is the correct GLib.Variant for this?

I've created the below script to test with a USB pen drive. It assumes /dev/sdc1 as this device.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

MYDEVICE = '/dev/sdc1'

import gi
gi.require_version('UDisks', '2.0')
from gi.repository import UDisks, GLib

read_only = GLib.Variant('a{sv}', {'read-only': GLib.Variant('b', True)})

client = UDisks.Client.new_sync(None)
manager = client.get_object_manager()
for obj in manager.get_objects():
    block = obj.get_block()
    if not block: continue
    device_path = block.get_cached_property("Device").get_bytestring().decode('utf-8')
    if device_path == MYDEVICE:
        fs = obj.get_filesystem()
        mount_points = fs.call_mount_sync(read_only, None)
        print((mount_points))
```

This will mount the device but it is not mounted read-only.

I would have expected it to mount the device as read-only or at least throw an error if the read-only option is not valid.

Comment: Try `GLib.Variant('a{sv}', {'options': GLib.Variant('s', 'ro')})`.

Comment: That's it! I've been looking for documentation on how to use Glib.Variant in regard to Udisks2 but never found anything. Knowing now how to use options this way, you can use any other available option. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, thanks for testing. I’ve written this up as a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GLib.Variant('a{sv}', {'options': GLib.Variant('s', 'ro')})` to pass the standard `ro` option through to [`mount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount).

See the [`Mount()` documentation for udisks’ D-Bus interface](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem.html#gdbus-method-org-freedesktop-UDisks2-Filesystem.Mount).